# Objective-C subclass setup

Tags: objective-c, oop, subclass, init

I have 3 Objective-C classes:

```
Animal - a subclass of NSObject
Feline - a subclass of Animal
Cat - subclass of Feline
```

Each of these three classes implement (what I thought was) its own private method (-private_Setup), for setup:

e.g. in Animal:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self private_Setup];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Same thing in the Feline and Cat classes.

A list of required classes is provided at runtime, so I am creating instances of the various classes, depending on a list of class names.

e.g.

```
NSString *className = ... // @"Animal", @"Feline" or @"Cat".
id animal = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

**Problem:**

If I create an instance of Cat, -private_Setup is being called multiple times, for each step in the inheritance chain. For example, the calling chain for a Cat:

```
-[Cat init]
-[Feline init]
-[Animal init]
-[Cat private_Setup]    // First!
```

then, from:

```
-[Feline init]
-[Cat private_Setup]    // Second!
```

then, from:

```
-[Cat init]
-[Cat private_Setup]    // Third!
```

Thus, what I thought was a method private to each class, is being called after each -init in the hierarchy.

Could someone please advise how I could either fix this issue or redesign my setup strategies? Thankyou.

[edited, appended for clarity]

Some form of setup is required at each level of the inheritance, to supply data particular to that level. e.g. Cat specific settings.

Thus, what I need is for a Cat object to be fully set up as an Animal, as a Feline, and as a Cat.

I guess one approach is to have different setup method names at each level. e.g. setupAnimal, setupFeline, setupCat.

e.g. in Animal:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupAnimal];
    }
    return self;
}
```

// in Feline:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupFeline];
    }
    return self;
}
```

// in Cat:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setupCat];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there a better, more preferred design than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call `private_Setup` method just once - in `Animal`'s `init`. That's all. Implement in all subclasses, call just once in supercalass

You're saying that you need a different form of setup for each subclass. Of course! That's why what you do is you implement `private_Setup` in every subclass. Implement just like you need it for every particular subclass. It's called overriding. Inside overridden method call `[super private_Setup]`. You'll get exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying `super init` and super's `init` calls `private_Setup`, so why are you surprised?

I guess you're surprised because you expect each `init` in the chain to call its own class's `private_Setup`. But the thing to understand is that meaning of `self` changes depending on the original class of the instance that started the chain (polymorphism).

So, for example, if you call `self private_Setup` from Animal's `init` during the process of initializing a Cat, it is *Cat's* `private_Setup` that will be called. Thus, with the arrangement you've made, it is exactly true that on initialization of a Cat, Cat's `private_Setup` will be called three times and none of the others will be called.

The solution is simple: *don't use an extra method*. It is a capital mistake to have an initializer call *any* methods (and the problem you're having is one of the reasons why it's a mistake). Instead, simply perform the setup *in `init` itself*. That is what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are implying that the call to private_Setup happens in all of your subclasses' init methods too.

Remove the call to private_Setup from all but the top (e.g. Animal) init method. As long as all of them call `[super init]`, you'll get exactly one call to private_Setup.